# Rookie error - column or expression cannot be updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Thanks for taking the time to read this SQL rookie's belated plea; it's much appreciated.

I'm trying to run an update statement in Server Management Studio 2012 using code that I thought I'd used hundreds of times, but for some reason, it's throwing an error back at me. So maybe I haven't.

I've been looking at this one for a while, removed all my original aliases, tried rewriting it and experimenting with different joins. I've searched all over for similar errors, but most seem to point to using the wrong aliases or incorrect use of the `WHERE` clause. Either might be the case here, I admit, but none is similar to the situation I have.

Using `SELECT` on the statement gives me the results I was expecting and the code passed the syntax checks, but I'm getting this message.

> column or expression 'DIS_ID' cannot be updated

When I try to run it. I assume it's something simple that I'm doing wrong, as I'm fairly new at this, but I've exhausted everything I can think of trying. I will admit to not being an expert in different types of joins, but I get the same `SELECT` results using a `LEFT` or `RIGHT` join.

```
UPDATE
    DIS_Territories
SET
    DIS_Territories.DIS_ID = '1'
FROM
    DIS_Territories
INNER JOIN
    Territories
ON 
    DIS_Territories.BT_ID = Territories.BT_ID
WHERE        (BT_State = 'Louisiana') AND (BT_County = 'Bienville') OR
                         (BT_State = 'Louisiana') AND (BT_County = 'Bossier') OR
                         (BT_State = 'Louisiana') AND (BT_County = 'Richland') OR
                         (BT_State = 'Louisiana') AND (BT_County = 'Union') OR
                         (BT_State = 'Louisiana') AND (BT_County = 'Webster') OR
                         (BT_State = 'Louisiana') AND (BT_County = 'West Carroll')
```

The data type for the column I'm trying to amend is Integer, not allowing nulls. If I'm missing any crucial information, my apologies and I'd be very grateful if someone would let me know what else I should provide.

EDIT: The `DIS_Territories` table structure is as follows:

```
USE [live.data]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dis_Territories](
    [BDT_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BT_ID] [int] NULL,
    [DIS_ID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

For the record, I'm having the same issue on both my *development* and *live* databases.

Thanks very much if you're still reading.

-Rodger

Comment: Can you provide the schema for DIS_Territories ?

Comment: Is DIS_ID a computed column or an identity column ?. Are you using Management Studio to run the query?

Comment: Pls provide the create Table statement for your Table DIS_Territories. It would be helpful to find a solution.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks so much for getting involved - much appreciated. Oops, no line breaks on 'enter' here!

DIS_ID is not an ID column, it's a manually entered column that refers to the ID in a table not referenced here.

The Create statement is below.

`
USE [prod.data]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Belzona_Dis_Territories](
 [BDT_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [BT_ID] [int] NULL,
 [DIS_ID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
`

Comment: Hi @thepirat000 - I am using Management Studio to run the query, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks very much to everyone who took a look.

I've done most of my editing in the *edit rows* window, which is where I was encountering the error. I ran it in the *new query* window instead, and it went off without a hitch. Not 100% sure if the fault is on my end of Server Management Studio, but it seems to work for now. Fingers crossed.

Comment: What did you mean by "edit rows" and "new query window"? I am using SQL Server 2005, so I hope you know how to explain it in that platform

Answer (score 0):

I tested your SQL with my imaginary data in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d01e8/1) and it works just fine.

I have the same suspicions as the people leaving the comments, Is there something in the table you haven't noticed? Is the column identity or computed column? Is DIS_Territories a view?

Comment: Hi @JamesZ , thanks for taking a look. It's one of the most simple tables I have, so I'm not sure - I assumed it must be something to do with the JOIN statement. DIS_Territories isn't a view, it's simply a table to link IDs from my list of Distributors to my list of Territories. The '_ID' part of the column is probably badly named, as it isn't an identity column in this instance.

Comment: @Rodger The name in the create table is Belzona_Dis_Territories. Did you just change that for the question or is there something else related to this?

Comment: Ha, yes, sorry, that was my subtle 'get out of coming up as a Google alert' edit. Epic fail. I think I have managed to get this to work though (seems to work on the 'new query' tab, but not by editing 'edit rows' window), so hopefully I'll be back on shortly to confirm one way or another.

Comment: @Rodger I remember reading that the edit rows window has all sorts of bugs, don't remember where though. I don't use it myself so can't be sure.